# Как сделать направление если страница не найдена?

Tags: php, get

Как сделать направление если страница не найдена?
Например: `page.php?act=asd`

PHP код:

```
<?php 
if($_GET['act']==''){
    echo 'Settings';
} 
if($_GET['act']=='security'){
    echo 'General';
}
if($_GET['act']=='privacy'){
    echo 'Privacy';
}
?>
```

И этот код пойдет? Или есть другой решение если get пуст. Например просто `page.php`

```
if($_GET['act']==''){
    echo 'Settings';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если страница не найдена, то **перенаправление делать не надо.** Надо просто выдавать соответствующий НТТР заголовок

А для перебора значений с действием по умолчанию идеально подходит команда switch:

```
switch($_GET['act'])
{
    case 'security';
        echo 'General';
        break;

    case 'privacy';
        echo 'Privacy';
        break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); 
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо но ошибка `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\site\www\include\header.php:5) in Z:\home\site\www\settings.php on line 29`

Comment: @KYRAN, функцию `header()` можно использовать ДО отправки любой другой информации на страницу (включая текст ошибок)

Comment: @ArchDemon я понял спасибо!